# Keras LSTM model for binary classification with sequences

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I'm currently working on a bigger project.
**The goal is to automatically find split points in time series which splits the series into elementary patterns.**

I have a lot of training data in form of time series with **different lengths** and split points manually recorded on useful positions.
Basically, I have the `x`, `y`, `z` positions and the distances between those points over a centered window of the lengths 2, 25 and 50 (`dist2`, `dist25`, `dist50`). I also divided the room into a 3D grid and figured out in which cell the position lies (`cell_x`, `cell_y`, `cell_z`). I think this could be useful because elementary operations will more likely be in one or two cells.

[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]
cell_x, cell_y, cell_z based on size 50. The vertical red lines are the split points of the training data.

**Now I want to know at every point in the time series if it is a split point or not.**

In my opinion, these are enough features to start with but I think my Keras model isn't correct because the result is always and only 1 at the 0's time series index. It's basically, a binary classification problem based on past and future values. This was the reason I've tried to solve it with an **LSTM**. It looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape = (None, input_dim), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='adam',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Because I'm at the very beginning of the whole Machine Learning topic and the mass of materials is a bit overwhelming I'm here to ask for some help. I know that there are a lot of other things (bad training data, wrong features, wrong parameters, ...) which can cause to this results but I want to know how I can build a Keras model for this problem correctly. I already found a lot of Keras examples but I'm not sure if they fit the problem.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what kind of output you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry, I want to know for each point of the series if it is a split point or not.

Comment: Could you upload your I/O data?

Comment: Features and label of one record: https://gist.github.com/chryb/2b3312b0ab640a1f28c8cb2d3dbbd86e | The column is_keyframe represents the labels for each index. Based on a Stackoverflow question I transformed the data with the following to the right LSTM input format: https://gist.github.com/chryb/3de34ba44488012bf79ff4c51a2a43ae

Comment: Perhaps a question at the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) forum might get you a quick answer.

Comment: Use `model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'hard_sigmoid'))` to have output 0 or 1 only. Try to remove dropouts to see if the model can train. Check that you can overfit and if yes start adding back dropout until it improves results. You probably will have problems because predicting 0 always will give a 99% correctness and your model will learn it very fast. It may be very hard to move to 100% accuracy to have your split points predicted.

Comment: Additionally you say _It's basically, a binary classification problem based on past and future values._. LSTM can't use future data. It classifies the last data point that you feed in.

Comment: @Manngo Thank you a lot. Do you know something which is more suitable for this? Otherwise, I would try to develop features of future and past values beforehand.

Comment: @Manngo That's not entirely true. You can use Bidirectional LSTM which is commonly used for example in NLP to inspect context of a word (past and future values) in a sentence.

Comment: Additionally, what I'd be more aware of is how massively skewed the data are. In the data you provided there are only 2 class1 labels, and 229 class2 labels. That's not even 1%. Your network simply learned that predicting always 0 is the optimal actions because of how improbable (< 1%) it is that it would be wrong.

Comment: @Chryb how did you solve this problem finally? I am also working on a similar problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer:

First, in principle, you can feed your data into `Keras`'s LSTM and hope that the network learns how to spot what you call a split point. With enough (labelled) data, this seems like an interesting project, even though imbalanced classes may be a problem (which can surely be addressed using either weights, resampling techniques or some similar)! I believe all this has been said in the various comments already. If you don't really care about the time-dimension, you may also want to try to see how other network architectures perform.

On a more general level, I wonder though if a sequential neural network is the right approach for this. There are many tried and tested approaches in time series econometrics and related fields. They come under various names, from [structural break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_break), [change point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection) or parameter stability detection. If you want to decide if new data points belong to a different regime, then there might be some techniques in anomaly/outlier detection you may find useful. To find a suitable statistical test (which are meant to find the time index when a break occurrs) that is appropriate for your particular setting, you will probably have to dig a little bit into the [actual literature](https://www.google.com/search?q=structural%20break%20detection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1) as only few of these are readily available in open source packages (i.e. "few" as a fraction of everything that is out there). I know that there are a few options availabe in R packages ([click](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html), [click](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html)), and I am sure something similar exists in Python, though I am not very familiar with the statistics-packages in Python, so I can't link to any even though they surely exist.

If you are looking for an easily accessible high-level open-source solution, some people find [facebook's prophet](https://research.fb.com/prophet-forecasting-at-scale/) interesting, which allows you to model time series and which includes the ability to detect [change points](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/trend_changepoints.html), among other things, automatically. I am not sure to what extent your labelled split points could feed into the model to help learn these points, but a good starting point might be to see if the automatically detected points are similar to your labelled ones.